# What is the general format of a Software Design Specification?

Tags: documentation, api, uml, design

I'm trying to document a piece of software I wrote in detail. An SAS is too high level and doesn't cover the API. I found several examples of an SDS online, but I don't see a trend in their format.

I'm wondering if there are some general guidelines to writing a Software Design Specification or what the best approach is?

Comment: http://www.bradapp.com/docs/sdd.html

Comment: http://www.rivier.edu/faculty/vriabov/CS552_SW_Design_Specification_Example.pdf ... and several others that can be obtained by Googling 'Software Design Specification'.  They all take more or less the same form, essentially describing the software to be written in terms of the required classes, modules and methods, and any design constraints and conditions that apply.

Comment: related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80974/what-is-the-standard-for-modeling-modern-applications-prior-to-development?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do a lot worse than starting with the [DOD-STD-2167A Software Design Document Data Item Description](http://www.continuum.org/brentb/2167a-did-sdd.html).

The US Department of Defense has a lot of experience with software development, a lot more than any one company.  They also have a vested interest in actually getting software that did the job, and that could be maintained down the road.  They went to a lot of trouble to figure out what information needed to be in the various documents that support a software project, using experience from a large number of projects, and more than a few very expensive failures.

The Software Development Plan DID (available [here](http://sce.uhcl.edu/helm/ms_2167/over_2167.html)) includes a number of items that must be addressed.  If you look closely, you'll notice that those sections are written in the blood of program managers who failed to address those items.